# sizeof of structure and pointer to structure?

Tags: c, sizeof

I have following code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    uint32 *data;

    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(uint32_t));
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(uint32_t*));
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(*data));

}

**OUTPUT**:
4  // <-This is size uint32_t structure 
8  // <-Here I understand it is size of pointer which is equal to 8 
4  // <-What does it mean?
```

Does `sizeof(*data)` is correct way to allocate memory in `malloc(sizeof(*data))`?
I saw this kind of memory allocation in library source code and I cannot understand if somebody can explain I will be were glad. And feel free to correct title of question. Because I am not aware what does it mean. And if there is already same question asked before just point to this question in comments I will just close question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: perhaps also consider what casting does! like: `sizeof(*(uint16_t *)data)`

Comment: Maybe you can try: `char* p_char`; printf("%d\n", sizeof(*p_char));` and other types instead of `char`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it seems quite logic to me: you are asking about the size of `*data`: since it is a pointer on `uint32_t` that you dereferencing you get an `uint32_t`, hence the `4`

```
uint32_t * data; // pointer on uint32_t
uint32_t deref_data = *data; // uint32_t
```

`sizeof(*data)` == `sizeof(*(uint32_t*))` == `sizeof(uint32_t)`

About the `malloc` you can just:

```
uint32_t * data = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
```

Comment: Sorry can you explain bit more?

Comment: so sizeof(*data) always equal to sizeof(uint32_t)?

Comment: Since data is a pointer variable of type uint32_t, the size of the (dereferenced) pointer is the same as the size of uint32_t, while the size of a pointer is 8.

Comment: @Phoenix Yes because you declared `data` as an `uint32_t*`. When you dereferencing with the `*` operator you get back an `uint32_t`

Comment: Ok. I have one more question here why people getting use this style of coding instead of just sizeof(uint32_t)? Do you have any idea?

Comment: sizeof(*data) is far more specific: It not only will return the same result, but it tells anybody (including yourself) who reads the code in the future why you are taking whatever action requires the sizeof() operator.

Comment: Even if I can understand the reason which might be "I don't care about the type of `data`, just give me enough space to store it", I think it is a bad choice as it is not really readable. You should explicitly write the type you want to allocate in `malloc`

Comment: @Coconop - but by declaring sizeof(*data) you will secure yourself from making mistake when changing type of data.

Answer (score 2):

*sizeof* is a unary operator. It returns (calculates) size of it's argument in bytes. Argument to sizeof can be a type or an expression.

Frist two lines of your example provide a type as an argument to *sizeof* while the third line provides the expression.

Expression you have provided dereferences a pointer to uint32. Because final type of that expression is of type uint32 and it's size on your machine is 4 bytes, that's what you get.

Answer (score 0):

It means whatever data points to is 4 chars (usually bytes) big.

sizeof is an operator, sizeof(thing) is how many chars "thing" is big.

data points to a uint32, so it is 8 chars big (64 bits), and the thing it points to 4 chars (32 bits). so sizeof(*data) = sizeof(*(uint32*)) = sizeof(uint32) basically.